# Getting returned API result in different function in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

```
export function getNodeChartFilteredData(ChartContent, value) {
    let abs = "primary"
    let url = `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/home/get_node_chart_data_people?abs=${abs}`;
    fetch(url)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(res => {
        return res
    })
}


res = getNodeChartFilteredData()
console.log(res)
```

In ReactJS how can I get returned API result after complete in a different function?

My function is in utils so I want to call this function from different files.

I am always getting null data when I tried.

Comment: Did the Api call happened ? what was the result of the api call?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your API works correctly you are not chaining promises correctly

```
export function getNodeChartFilteredData(ChartContent, value) {
let abs = "primary"
let url = `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/home/get_node_chart_data_people?abs=${abs}`;
fetch(url)
.then(res => res.json()
.then(res => {
    return res
}))
```

}

Comment: `res.json()` doesn't return a promise, does it?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is one of asynchronicity. The Promise of `fetch` resolves in a different scope than the function you are trying to return something from. Could you structure your logic like this instead? This should work.

```js
export function getNodeChartFilteredData(ChartContent, value) {
    let abs = 'primary';
    let url = `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/home/get_node_chart_data_people?abs=${abs}`;
    return fetch(url)
      .then(res => res.json())
}

getNodeChartFilteredData()
  .then(res => {
    console.log(res)
  });
```

This returns the promise so you can act on its resolution (`then`) in the calling scope. Alternatively you could pass a callback to `getNodeChartFilteredData`, but it's not good practice to mix promise based logic with old-school callbacks.

Comment: Still getting null data

Comment: It depends on how `fetch` function is written. If it is not returning any promise, then it will indeed not return the expected result.

Comment: I've tested this code with another service that returns json data, so I'm confident the code works as expected. Have you verified the response from the server is JSON data?